# Flutter Getx RxList Product List, Name-Price

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

i wanna create a Basket with Getx , i defined a values as Name and Price, i wanna add  Basic a Product in to Shop Basket. How can i add a String as name or double as Price from Product into PriceModel2 -RxList ?

Product Model-

```
class PriceModel2 {
  String name;
  double price;

  PriceModel2(String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

Add Function

```
RxList<PriceModel2> basket = [].obs;

  urunEkle(String isim) {
    basket.add(isim);
    basket.add(isim<basket>[name]);
  }
```

UI

```
 ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.urunEkle(
                    material["name"] );
```

Thanks for all Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Model:

```
class PriceModel2 {
  final String name;
  final double price;

  PriceModel2( {required this.name,required this.price,});
}
```

Function:

```
List<PriceModel2> basket = <PriceModel2>[].obs;

void urunEkle(String isim, double fiyat) {
  basket.add(PriceModel2(name: isim, price: fiyat));
}
```

Ui:

```
 ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      controller.urunEkle("isim", 9.00);
    },
```

**This code works if you use null safety**

Comment: hi , its giving this Problem. https://prnt.sc/1fno776 , also i added final Tag before the String and Double then coming that , https://prnt.sc/1fnoryx

Comment: Its working without required ! , Im glad to u Sir , Herrlich !https://prnt.sc/1fnsor7

Comment: Great! happy to help